# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value in read-only MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, output, truncated

I have "reader" jurisdiction in a database I work with.

The following query even though it returns the columns with the values I require, it also opens an "output" window depicting multiple times the message "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: (name of our client's name)"

```
select u.email ,u.* from ss_users su 
join user u on u.userid = su.userid 
where su.ss_id = 330208783 
and su.ext_id in (1976776,1987431,1873593);
```

I have altered the names of the tables and columns for privacy purposes in case you find any typos.

Could you please advise why I am also getting this message in the output? Thank you in advance.

**edit after reading the comments:**

```
ss_users: CREATE TABLE `ss_users` (
  `user_id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ss_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `ext_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ext_id`,`user_id`,`ss_id`),
  KEY `user_fk` (`user_id`),
  KEY `ss_user_idx` (`ss_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `sso_ext_idx` (`ss_id`,`ext_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

user: CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `auth` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'email',
  `gender` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_page` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `api_key` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateofbirth` bigint(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '5',
  `official_code` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `picture_uri` mediumtext,
  `creator_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `competences` mediumtext,
  `openarea` mediumtext,
  `productions` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_school` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `institution` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `concestrations` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `books` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `movies` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `music` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tv` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `about` mediumtext,
  `job` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chatcall_user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `chatcall_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `chatcall_text` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_logout_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirm` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '1',
  `active` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '1',
  `activation` int(11) DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT 'confirmed email - correct field',
  `change_password` int(11) DEFAULT '-1',
  `change_language` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '-1',
  `theme` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` mediumtext,
  `n_personal_website` mediumtext,
  `n_company_website` mediumtext,
  `l_blog` text,
  `l_favorite_website` mediumtext,
  `l_company_website` mediumtext,
  `l_personal_website` mediumtext,
  `l_other_website` mediumtext,
  `settings` mediumtext,
  `removed_bookmarklet` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `change_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `closed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `grid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `security` mediumtext,
  `newsletter` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `headline` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkForm` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `whattodonow` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastactivity` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `uname_idx` (`uname`),
  KEY `lastname_idx` (`lastname`),
  KEY `change_email_idx` (`change_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2162466900 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: It sounds like you’re using a SQL client and you’re also using table definitions. It would be far easier to help if added information about them as additional and essential context.

Comment: Tag your question with the RDBMS you're using. "SQL" is a language used by many different database systems.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I have added the appropriate tag. It's in "MySql"

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE of both tables.